# Finish loop of ajax calls array instead of breaking on error from one of calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, jquery-callback

I'm trying to make loop of ajax calls from an array and saving each data result that I'll print when all calls are successfully received.

The problem is that if there is any ajax call returning error, the whole process is aborted and the callback is not executed. (Try using listWithErrorResult)

How to push something on error without breaking the loop?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mhlavacka/MBZEu/130/)

```js
var list = ['UQ13nr6urIo', 'hxa_Z0eZ83E', 'ulHB2mNlovg'];
var listWithErrorResult = ['UQ13nr6urIo', 'hxa_Z0eZ83E', 'IWEHeIdBkc4'];

var callback = function() {
  console.log("done");
  console.log(tracks);
};

var requests = [], tracks = [];

  for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    requests.push($.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+list[i],
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('suc');
        tracks.push(data);
      },error: function() {
       console.log('err');
       tracks.push('err');
     }
    }));
  }

$.when.apply(undefined, requests).then(function(results){callback()});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just attach a `.then()` handle to your ajax call and make sure every ajax call resolves rather than rejects.  This will get you an array of results at the end that is guaranteed to include all your ajax calls.:

```
var callback = function(/* tracks are passed here as arguments */) {
  console.log("done");
  var tracks = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  console.log(tracks);
};

var requests = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    requests.push($.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+list[i],
      dataType: "json",
    }).then(function(data) {
        return data;
    }, function(err) {
        // convert failure into success so $.when() doesn't stop
        return $.Deferred().resolve('err');
    }));
  }

$.when.apply($, requests).then(callback);
```

---

You can also use a version of `$.settle()` that I wrote that lets all promises finish and gives you all results, even if some promises reject.

Instead of `$.when()` (which stops on the first rejected promise), you can use this new function `$.settle()` which returns you the results of all the promises.  It returns an array of PromiseInspection objects which allow you to query the resolved value or rejected reason for each promise.

You use `$.settle()` just like `$.when()` except it returns all results in PromiseInspection objects and it always resolves (never rejects).  Because of jQuery's non-standard means of passing multiple arguments to `.then()` handlers (particular Ajax calls), if `.settle()` detects multiple arguments, it copies them into an array so the PromiseInspection.value returned from a successful ajax call is an array `[data, textStatus, jqXHR]`.  This is the worst part of jQuery's non-standard promises.  Presumably this is fixed/changed in jQuery 3.x which is supposed to be standard's compliant.  This code will work with either since it auto-detects if the `.then()` handler is sent more than one argument and converts them into a single array argument.

```
// ES6 version of settle
jQuery.settle = function(promises) {
    function PromiseInspection(fulfilled, val) {
        return {
            isFulfilled: function() {
                return fulfilled;
            }, isRejected: function() {
                return !fulfilled;
            }, isPending: function() {
                // PromiseInspection objects created here are never pending
                return false;
            }, value: function() {
                if (!fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .value() on a promise that is not fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }, reason: function() {
                if (fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .reason() on a promise that is fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }
        };
    }

    return $.when.apply($, promises.map(function(p) {
        return p.then(function(val) {
            if (arguments.length > 1) {
                val = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            }
            return new PromiseInspection(true, val);
        }, function(err) {
            if (arguments.length > 1) {
                err = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            }
            return new PromiseInspection(false, err);
        });
    }));
}
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer this question. I only accepted the answer above bc it was simpler in this particular use case.

Comment: @mhlavacka - If you want to make sure your callback is passed ALL the results, even if some ajax calls fail, then I've added a very simple way to do that to the start of my answer.  That other answer will not give you all the results.  It will make sure that callback is always called, but you won't necessarily have all results when the callback is called.

Comment: You're right, just realized it stops after one ajax calls fail.

Comment: This works above right, but how do I push to tracks array on error as well, please?  - http://jsfiddle.net/mhlavacka/MBZEu/131/

Comment: @mhlavacka - In my implementation, the tracks array is passed as the first argument to the callback.  `$.when()` accumulates the array of results for you so you don't have to do that manually.  If you just makes sure that each promise resolves with the desired value, then `$.when()` automatically creates that array of results for you.  That's why I use both  `.then()` handlers on the ajax function itself so I can control the resolved value to be what you want in the array.

Comment: I see now, exactly what I needed. thanks for helping out!

Comment: @mhlavacka - See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wtkcu83t/ for how to use the results in the callback.  jQuery's non-standard handling of `$.when()` confused me.  It is not passed an array of results.  It is passed N arguments so I added code in my jsFiddle there to convert the arguments into your tracks array.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add error callback to `$.when.apply` `then` too as its an error condition when one of the call fails.

```
$.when.apply(undefined, requests).then(
    function(results){callback()}, 
    function(results){callback()}
);
```

Working jsBin [here](https://jsbin.com/judapacina/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: This will not give you all results.  `$.when()` stops gathering results as soon as any promise rejects.  So, if one of the ajax calls fails, this will not give you complete results.  It will guarantee that the callback is always called, but the callback will not be called with all results (which is what I thought the OP wanted).

Comment: That's true. It executes failed call, but stops right after it.